# Working with Ruby on Rails Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

I am new to ruby on rails and have a (probably simple) question regarding performance and best-practice for **Rails 3**.  I am using a blog engine called enki blog, and I see that the person who wrote this blog engine is selecting tags using the following technique:

```
Tag.find(:all).reject {|tag| tag.taggings.empty? }.sort_by {|tag| tag.taggings_count }.reverse
```

I see no purpose of the ".reject" since empty tags are removed any time an article is created, updated, or destroyed.  Assuming I am right about that, would this be a better approach?

```
Tag.find(:all, :order => "taggings_count desc")
```

I am looking for performance and readability.  What is the best way to drill-down the results of a model?  Is there any real difference between ".sort_by" and passing :order as a parameter?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: are you using rails3? If I remember right, `find` with additional parameters (such as the `:order`) is deprecated. I would suggest `Tag.order("taggings_count desc")` which is cleaner :)

Comment: Yes, I am using rails 3.  Tag.order("taggings_count desc") do the same thing as Tag.find(:all, :order => "taggings_count desc") ?  Does it implicitly select all?  If so, does .order have the same level of performance as the parameterised version?

Comment: It is going to be deprecated in Rails 3.1. There is no reason to use old-style syntax in new projects. I'd suggest you watch [the railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3) to learn the differences if you are curious.

Comment: Better watch the railscast link by @Semyon Perepelitsa. In short, `find` reduced to have only 1 param, which might be `:all / :first / :last / ID`. Those conditions are separate methods (`where / order / join etc` returning ActiveRelation (not query the DB until actually use the records, such as calling `.all / .first etc`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, that is definitely some inefficient code.

There is a significant difference between sort_by and :order. :order is used to build the SQL statement, meaning the database sorts the records before it returns them. sort_by is a Ruby method which rearranges the records the database has already returned. Generally the database is going to be much faster, so user :order.

I can't speak as to whether reject is necessary or not. But if it *is*, again it would be much quicker to do it in the database with a WHERE statement. So you would have

```
Tag.find(:all, :conditions => "taggings_count > 0", :order => "taggings_count desc")
```

In Rails 3 that would look like

```
Tag.where('taggings_count > 0').order('taggings_count desc')
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  It is very helpful, but I forgot to mention I am using Rails 3.  Is the :order as a parameter deprecated as the commenter above me says?  I will edit my post to mention that I'm using rails 3.

Comment: If you use old syntax, where conditions are specified inside `:conditions => {}` hash

Comment: Oh, I accidentally created a weird synthesis of Rails 2 and 3 styles. As of Rails 3 it would look like Tag.where('taggings_count > 0').order('taggings_count desc')